# Can I access a context in a react-router-dom loader function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a AuthContext to handle my login status.

Then I want to perform route protection for the logined information page before it's loaded, so I write a loader function like this:

```
export function checkAuthLoader() {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(authCtx.isLogin);
  if (!authCtx.isLogin) return redirect('/');

  return null;
}
```

It doesn't work and warn me that `React Hook "useContext" is called in function "checkAuthLoader" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.`

So I ask the chatGPT and It gave me a solution like make the loader function as a component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from './AuthContext';

class RouterLoader extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AuthContext;

  routerLoaderFunction() {
    const { isLoggedIn } = this.context;
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      // If the user is not logged in, redirect to the login page
      this.props.history.push('/login');
      return null;
    }
    // If the user is logged in, continue rendering the protected route
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    return this.routerLoaderFunction();
  }
}
```

Is it a ideal way to perform that? Because it look weird that I have to render a auth component to check my auth status before accessing the target component. If I have to render a component to check it, I might as well just check it in the useEfffect() of my target component.

Does anyone know how to access the context in a loader function directly?